# How to track shipments in FedEx Web Services testing environment?

Tags: fedex

I'm using FedEx Web Services testing environment with a set of test credentials. I got the pair of `ProcessShipment`/`DeleteShipment` requests working:

1. `ProcessShipment` creates a new shipment and returns a tracking number.
2. `DeleteShipment` deletes the shipment, given the tracking number from step 1.

Now when I send `TrackShipment` query in between these two steps, it responds with "This tracking number cannot be found.". **The question is:** why wouldn't `TrackShipment` find the tracking number when `DeleteShipment` does?

This is what my `TrackShipment` request looks like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v16">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <TrackRequest>
            <WebAuthenticationDetail>...</WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ClientDetail>...</ClientDetail>
            <Version>
                <ServiceId>trck</ServiceId>
                <Major>16</Major>
                <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
                <Minor>0</Minor>
            </Version>
            <SelectionDetails>
                <CarrierCode>FDXE</CarrierCode>             
                <PackageIdentifier>
                    <Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</Type>
                    <Value>794635174178</Value>
                </PackageIdentifier>
            </SelectionDetails>
        </TrackRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

FedEx Web Services documentation has a list of mock tracking numbers, at least one of them returns proper tracking information when I send it with the above request. One might think that, since FedEx provides mock tracking numbers, testing environment doesn't really keep track of shipments and only mock tracking numbers are supposed to return positive results. However, `DeleteShipment` request behaves as if the shipment is real, not mocked.

P.S. I verified that `CarrierCode` is the same as the one returned by `ProcessShipment`.

Comment: Can you send non-existing tracking number to DeleteShipment?

Comment: When I send DeleteShipment request with non-existing tracking number, it responds with "Unable to retrieve record from the database". When I send repeated DeleteShipment request with the tracking number of the shipment that  has just been deleted, it responds with "Shipment Delete was requested for a tracking number already in a deleted state.". So it looks like testing environment  retains created shipments in a persistent storage and this is why I expect TrackShipment to return the status.